# Algorithm to calculate 'initial lists' in O(m*log m)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, big-o

Goal is to write an algorithm that calculates 'initial lists' (a data-structure) in a complexity class better than O(m^2)

**What are initial list?**

Let `U` be a set of tuples (for example `{(2,5), (5,1), (9,0), (6,4)}` ).

Step 1:

L1 is ordered by the first element of the tuple:

```
L1 = [ (2,5), (5,1), (6,4), (9,0) ]
```

and L2 by the second:

```
L2 = [ (9,0), (5,1), (6,4), (2,5) ]
```

Step 2:

Add the indices of tuple e in the second list to the tuple e in the first list:

```
L1 = [ (2,5,3), (5,1,1), (6,4,2), (9,0,0) ]
```

and the other way:

```
L2 = [ (9,0,3), (5,1,1), (6,4,2), (2,5,0) ]
```

**L1 and L2 are called the initial lists of U now.**

---

The first implementation idea of course is an exhaustive algorithm in O(m^2)

```
U = {(2,5), (5,1), (9,0), (6,4)}

m = len(U)

#step 1:
L1 = [e for e in U]
L1.sort()
L2 = [e for e in U]
L2.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])

#step 2:
help = []*len(L1)
for i in range(len(L1)):
    help[i] = L1[i][0], L1[i][1], L2.index(L1[i])

for i in range(len(L2)):
    L2[i] = L2[i][0], L2[i][1], L1.index(L2[i])

L1 = help

# >>> L1
# [(2, 5, 3), (5, 1, 1), (6, 4, 2), (9, 0, 0)]
# >>> L2
# [(9, 0, 3), (5, 1, 1), (6, 4, 2), (2, 5, 0)]
```

So this works. But calling index ( O(m) ) in a for-loop ( O(m) ) makes its complexity quadratic. But how to write an algorithm for that in O(m*log m)?

Comment: Are the tuples in the initial list constrained in some way? e.g., are repetitions possible `{(1,1), (1,2)}`, and non-continuity `{(1, 1), (2,5000)}`?

Comment: They do not need to be constrained in some way (you can use random tuples if you want). If you create the lists from a set, there are no duplicates. But I tried it: Duplicates do also work: L1 = [(2, 5, 3), (2, 5, 4), (5, 1, 1), (6, 4, 2), (9, 0, 0)] and L2 = [(9, 0, 4), (5, 1, 2), (6, 4, 3), (2, 5, 0), (2, 5, 1)]

Comment: Allowing duplicates does make the output non-deterministic though. For `U = {(1, 1), (1, 2)` both `[(1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0)]` and `[(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1)]` are valid `L2`s, unless you allow secondary sorting criteria. Is that alright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. One possibility in O(m * log m) is just sorting 3 times. The sorting function List.sort() is O(m * log m) in Python:

```
from copy import deepcopy

U = {(2,5), (5,1), (9,0), (6,4)}
m = len(U)

h = sorted(U) #O(m * log m)
for i in range(len(h)): #O(m)
  (u,v) = h[i]
  h[i] = (u,v,i)
h.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1]) #O(m * log m)

L1 = deepcopy(h)
L2 = h

for i in range(len(L1)): #O(m)
  (u,v,_) = L1[i]
  L1[i] = (u,v,i) #reset indices i
L1.sort() #O(m * log m)

print(L1)
print(L2)

# [(2, 5, 3), (5, 1, 1), (6, 4, 2), (9, 0, 0)]
# [(9, 0, 3), (5, 1, 1), (6, 4, 2), (2, 5, 0)]
```

Answer (score 4):

I see room for some optimisation here.

- Sort twice as before, but create two dictionaries for looking up the index (this is linear in time).
- You can also use `operator.itemgetter` to remove the lambdas.
- You also can junk the copy calls, they're not needed when you call `sorted` anyway, because `sorted` returns a copy of your data.

```
from operator import itemgetter
ip = {(2,5), (5,1), (9,0), (6,4)}

# step 1 - sort `ip` and create L1
L1 = sorted(ip)
# step 2 - create index lookup for L2
idx_L1 = {k : v for v, k in enumerate(L1)}

# step 3, 4 - repeat for L2
L2 = sorted(ip, key=itemgetter(1))
idx_L2 = {k : v for v, k in enumerate(L2)}

# step 5 - augment L1 and L2 with respective indexes from other lists
L1 = [(*x, idx_L2[x]) for x in L1]   # starred unpacking - python3.6+ syntax
L2 = [(*x, idx_L1[x]) for x in L2]   # use `x + (idx_L2[x],)` for older versions
```

```
>>> L1
[(2, 5, 3), (5, 1, 1), (6, 4, 2), (9, 0, 0)]    
>>> L2
[(9, 0, 3), (5, 1, 1), (6, 4, 2), (2, 5, 0)]
```

Comment: Note that this has a worst-case runtime of O(n²).  The amortized runtime is O(n log n).

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks, that clarification is helpful. OP could consider merge sort as an alternative, if their data could possibly trigger those worst case sorting scenarios.

Comment: No, it's not because of the sort algorithm – Tim Sort has a worst-case runtime of O(n²).  The problem is the dictionaries.  A lookup is only amortized O(1), but can be O(n) in the worst case.

Comment: Darn, I meant to say that Tim Sort has a worst-case runtime of O(n log n).  I definitely didn't get enough sleep last night.